# Parentheses under equation with function surrounding

Tags: equations, alignat

I want to obtain parantheses under equation like this:

[image: desired_output]

I can write the equation without `\Phi{}` term, however, I cannot manage to write this function `\Phi` there surrounding the RHS of equation.

The code I have now, which is not working is:

```
$$
\begin{alignat*}{5}
 &\hat{Pr}(deny = 1| pirat, black)  = {}&&\Phi{  {}&&-0.091 + {}&&0.559 
       pirat + {}&&0.177 black} \\
       &         &&     &&(0.033)    && (0.104)        &&(0.025)  
 \end{alignat*}
 $$
```

Is it possible to do it somehow inside this `alignat*` environment?

Comment: don't use `$$` in latex, also don't use math italic for words, so use `\mathrm{black}`  or `\mathit{black}` not `black`  for the actual question don't you just want to use `(...)` not `{...}` after `\Phi`  (please always post a complete test document not just a fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `\mathop{<top>}_{<bottom>}`, or if you want more control, load the `stackengine` package and you can use something like `\stackMath\Shortunderstack{{<top>} {<bottom>}}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\Pr(\widehat{\mathrm{deny}=1|\mathrm{pirat}, \mathrm{black}})= \Phi(\mathop{-0.091}_{(0.033)} + \mathop{0.559}_{(0.104)} \mathrm{pirat} + \mathop{0.177}_{(0.25)}\, \mathrm{black})
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]